# vim: prevent composite mapping from acting as its suffix

Tags: vim

I have mappings to copy/cut/paste to/from register:

```
nnoremap <c-r><c-c>a "ayy   -- copy current line into register a
nnoremap <c-r><c-x>a "add   -- cut current line into register a
nnoremap <c-r><c-v>a "ap    -- paste from register a
```

and same for all other registers and modes. I also have usual mappings for c-c/x/v to act as copy, cut and paste to/from unnamed register. Now if I press <kbd>c-r c-v a</kbd> quickly, then everything works, but if I press c-r c-v and pause to think which register to use, vim decides to act on c-v instead (performs paste from unnamed register).

**Is there a way to make such mappings work without conflict in vim? So that when I press c-r c-v it won't timeout and become c-v.**

In standard keymap I think this works via some "waiting-for-register-letter-mode". For instance if I use c-r in command line mode vim displays " and waits for a register letter indefinitely, same in normal mode when pressing ".

EDIT: vim help mentions that remapping c-c in normal mode breaks ability to interrupt scripts. True, but the question still applies when using something else like c-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to `:set notimeout` to disable behavior completely, or `:set timeoutlen=5000` to increase the default timeout to e.g. 5 seconds. See `:help map-typing` for details